# Use Libusb in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

I'm using `VS2013` on `Windows 7 64bit`, I have read this topic  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/page__hl__USB
and try to compile it on `VS2013`, but I having problem.
Here is compile error message:

```
Error   12  error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals   C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\Debug\LIBUSB.exe LIBUSB

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_init@4 referenced in function _wmain  C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\LIBUSB\LIBUSB.obj    LIBUSB

Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_exit@4 referenced in function _wmain  C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\LIBUSB\LIBUSB.obj    LIBUSB

Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_set_debug@8 referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\LIBUSB\LIBUSB.obj    LIBUSB

Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_get_device_list@8 referenced in function _wmain   C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\LIBUSB\LIBUSB.obj    LIBUSB
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_free_device_list@8 referenced in function _wmain  C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\LIBUSB\LIBUSB.obj    LIBUSB

Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_get_device_descriptor@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl printdev(struct libusb_device *)" (?printdev@@YAXPAUlibusb_device@@@Z)   C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\LIBUSB\LIBUSB.obj    LIBUSB

Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_get_config_descriptor@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl printdev(struct libusb_device *)" (?printdev@@YAXPAUlibusb_device@@@Z)  C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\LIBUSB\LIBUSB.obj    LIBUSB

Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libusb_free_config_descriptor@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl printdev(struct libusb_device *)" (?printdev@@YAXPAUlibusb_device@@@Z)  C:\Users\HoangNam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LIBUSB\LIBUSB\LIBUSB.obj    LIBUSB
```

I think I need link `usblib` to my project but I don't know how to do that.
Pls help me :(

Comment: Did you include proper libusb.lib?

Comment: Should be included like: Project Properties -> Linker -> Input [Additional Dependencies].

Comment: I can't found libusb.lib in libusb 1.0.18 folder, so i can't include it

Comment: @HoangNam The site you link to says you have to build libusb yourself. Have you done so ? Which version/file of libusb have you downloaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution must be opened from `msvc` folder and built. Then there will be `.lib` & `.dll` files you need. Copy them to project folder and add like Andro said. It works.